# Create a dynamic workflow with Spring and Activiti

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, workflow

Good evening,

I work on an application designed to implement a workflow that allows the management of the traceability of the activities carried out by employees (called collaborators) within any type of organization.

What I want to do is set the tasks, ie the administrator can create a new process, add a task to a process ...

I want to know if it is possible to create a kind of workflow that is dynamic can be set by the user from the web browser.